# What Version of Asp.Net MVC is in Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

What Version of Asp.Net MVC is in Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Is it MVC 2 RC 2? or RC 1? Or ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Haacked](http://twitter.com/haacked/status/8862040856) says

> VS 2010 RC contains ASP.NET MVC 2 RC. MVC 2 RC 2 was finished after the final build of VS2010 RC.

Answer (score 0):

And as far as I can tell you cannot even get MVC 1 solutions to work with VS 2010.